# favicon.ico 404

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, iis-7, http-status-code-404

I have an icon for favicon in my master page (let's say I have ~/resources/company.ico defined).
Now if this company.ico doesn't exist, the browser (tested ie and mozilla) will try to look for default favicon name, which is ~/favicon.ico. If the last doesn't exist, it will 404 directly to the user screen.

This is something very different to if for ex. I put a link to not existing css file, where the browser will hide this 404 from the user and show the page without this resource.

Why are these 2 situations behaving so differently?
Is this situation only possible with favicon.ico or can it happen with other "specific" type of resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably in my initial question there was not enough info, I was expecting someone pointing out that it should not behave like that. This was later proved by having a static page with missing favicon, which was handling 404 for this resource gracefully.

The answer actually was to do with Run All Modules options on http modules in the web.config, due to what static files (CSS, JS, *.ico, etc.) were run through ASP.Net pipeline.

We are using cassette for serving static files and the version of cassette we were using was not supporting RAMMFAR option being off.

These were changes to web.config, which stopped incorrect behaviour:

```
<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="false">
    <add name="CassetteHttpModule" type="Cassette.Aspnet.CassetteHttpModule, Cassette.Aspnet" />
    <add name="AuthenticationModule" type="ProjName.Web.HttpModules.AuthenticationModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
    <add name="ErrorModule" type="ProjName.Web.HttpModules.ErrorModule" preCondition="managedHandler" />
</modules>
```

Thank's everyone who was trying to help.

Resources which helped:

Scott Hanselman: http://www.hanselman.com/blog/BackToBasicsDynamicImageGenerationASPNETControllersRoutingIHttpHandlersAndRunAllManagedModulesForAllRequests.aspx

Rick Strahl: http://www.west-wind.com/weblog/posts/2012/Oct/25/Caveats-with-the-runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests-in-IIS-78

Answer (score 3):

This behavior is only relatad to the favicon and depends on the browser implementation.

Comment: This behaviour was related not only to favicon.